# Regex to validate characters and numbers concatenated with -

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string that Characters and numbers cannot be concatenated, if you want to concatenate use a hyphen.

For example, these should all match:

- abc-123-123-***
- 123-abc-abc-***
- 123-abc-123-***
- abc-123-abc-***
- abc-efg-***

not match:

- abc123
- 123abc
- abc1
- a1b2
  Please help me to find a javascript regex.

Please help me to find a javascript regex.

Comment: "Characters and numbers": does that mean *letters* and numbers, or do you mean that numbers cannot be concatenated with *anything* else (except hyphen)?

Answer (score 1):

My regex is quite complex :

```
^([^\d\-]+|\d+)(\-([^\d\-]+|\d+))*$
```

Test string is matched or not in javascript:

```
/^([^\d\-]+|\d+)(\-([^\d\-]+|\d+))*$/gi.test('abc-123-123-***')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply test for transition from alpha to digit, or digit to alpha, and take the logical opposite of that:

```js
[
  'abc-123-123-***',
  '123-abc-abc-***',
  '123-abc-123-***',
  'abc-123-abc-***',
  'abc-efg-***',
  'abc123',
  '123abc',
  'abc1',
  'a1b2',
].forEach(str => {
  var ok = !/\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d/.test(str);
  console.log(str, ' ==> ', ok);
});
```